# What is the best way to reduce clicks and improve the product list page UX on mobile devices?

Tags: e-commerce, responsive-design, redesign

I'll be glad if you share your opinions and experience about one interesting case. I have to reduce the clicks and to improve the UX of a product list page. Responsive website, the product list page is a pretty standard: product with title, sku, counter and "add to cart button", also additional button on the top of all products "add all to cart", with it you could set only the quantity and not to click every time "add to cart". The products are well known for the customers, so they don't have to review them. The clients thought that they have to make a lot of clicks because they set the quantity and click every time "add to cart button". What do you think will be the best solution that can be offered in this case?

Comment: Hi @Danielillo, all the questions are related to the UX improvement. Is this a problem? Should I create another three similar questions instead? Sorry, I'm new here as a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions, but all depend on the type of product for sale, if they have variations or if they are unique products.

1. If the buyer adds quantities to different products, they don't need to click the add button for each item. Once all the quantities have been placed, clicking on `Add all to cart` would be enough
2. In our online store we have a `Quick buy` button. This button opens a window with a search field at the top to place the product's SKU which are placed below line by line. Once all the SKU and their corresponding quantities have been inserted, you can click on the `Add to cart` button. This is very useful for clients who have an Excel with the list of products to buy because they make an immediate purchase without practically having to navigate in the store.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the products are unique. They haven’t variations. Ordinary, every user purchase 10-20 different products with at least 10qty/each.

Comment: In that case, giving to the *Add all to cart* button the *super-power* of going over the add-to-cart button would be enough, as described in point one of the answer. The clients just need to put the quantities at each product and then *Add all to cart*